# У div элемент задана ширина и висата, когда даю елементу box-sizing:border-box, то ширина и висата как будто испараетца, почему?

Tags: html, css3

```css
#trapezoid {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid black;
  border-top: 50px solid yellow;
  border-right: 50px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`box-sizing`**

Применяется для изменения алгоритма расчёта ширины и высоты элемента.

Согласно спецификации CSS ширина блока складывается из ширины содержимого (`width`), значений `margin`, `padding` и `border`. Аналогично обстоит и с высотой блока. Свойство `box-sizing` позволяет изменить этот алгоритм, чтобы свойства `width` и `height` задавали размеры не содержимого, а размеры блока.

- **`content-box`** - 
  Основывается на стандартах CSS, при этом свойства `width` и `height` задают ширину и высоту содержимого и не включают в себя значения `margin`, `padding` и `border`.
- **`border-box`** - 
  Свойства `width` и `height` включают в себя значения `padding` и `border`, но не `margin`.

[Источник - webref.ru](https://webref.ru/css/box-sizing)